# How to redefine variable type in method context in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a webgl application with typescript.

I have the following code snippet:

```js
import { Mat3, Mat4, Vec2, Vec3, Vec4 } from 'math';

type Nullable<T> = T | null;
type UniformInputValue = Nullable<number | boolean | Vec2 | Vec3 | Vec4 | Mat3 | Mat4>;

class UniformInput {
  // ...other fields
  public type: number;
  public value: UniformInputValue;
  public location: WebGLUniformLocation;
  public setValue: (gl: WebGLRenderingContext, value: UniformInputValue) => void;

  constructor (options) {
    const gl = options.gl;
    this.type = options.type;
    this.location = options.location;
    this.value = null;
    switch (this.type) {
      case gl. FLOAT_VEC2:
        this.value = new Vec2();
        this.setValue = this.setFloatVec2;
        break;
      case gl. FLOAT_VEC3:
        this.value = new Vec3();
        this.setValue = this.setFloatVec3;
        break;
      // ...
    }
  }

  setFloatVec2(gl: WebGLRenderingContext, value: Vec2) {
    if (!this.value.equals(value)) {
      this.value.copy(value);
      gl.uniform2f(this.location, this.value.x, this.value.y);
    }
  }

  setFloatVec3(gl: WebGLRenderingContext, value: Vec3) {
    if (!this.value.equals(value)) {
      this.value.copy(value);
      gl.uniform3f(this.location, this.value.x, this.value.y, this.value.z);
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

However I get the following error message in all of my `setValue` method:

```
Property 'equals' does not exist on type 'number | boolean | Vec2 | Vec3 | Vec4 Mat3 | Mat4'.
Object is possibly 'null'.
```

[image]

I know a workaround is to type definition in all of the `setValue` method like:

```js
    private setFloatVec2(gl: WebGLRenderingContext, value: Vec2) {
        if (!(this.value as Vec2).equals(value)) {
            (this.value as Vec2).copy(value);

            if (this.location) gl.uniform2f(this.location, (this.value as Vec2).x, (this.value as Vec2).y);
        }
    }
```

But this is very annoying. I want something can change the type of `this.value` in method context.

Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `this.value` always not `null`? It seems like it might always be initialised looking at your constructor. If so, change the type of `value` in the class declaration (e.g. `public value: NonNullable<UniformInputValue>`). If not, the `setValue` methods are unsafe as `this.value` could be `null` and throw a runtime error. You could do something like `if (this.value === null) throw new Error('this.value cannot be null')` to fix this.

Comment: @cherryblossom the `setValue` is defined by `this.type` and I will check the `type` before I call `new UniformInput`.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from type assertion another workaround you may use is to explicitly [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function) `this` to the desired type:

```ts
class Vec2Input extends UniformInput {
  value: Vec2
}
...
  setFloatVec2(this: Vec2Input, gl: WebGLRenderingContext, value: Vec2) {
    if (!this.value.equals(value)) {
      this.value.copy(value);
      gl.uniform2f(this.location, this.value.x, this.value.y);
    }
  }
...
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m3AYLw)